# Explain to me how .join() works in Python

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x

I have created an answer validation code for use in a troubleshooting program. I have used the obvious validators for number answers (using the try/except method), however I now have yes/no questions as well. I scoured the internet and stack exchange and found one method that removes any integers from the answer (not just ones on the edges of an answer like `.strip()`). It uses the join method:

```
while True:
    a = input("Yes or No? ").lower()
    a = ''.join(c for c in a if c.isalpha())
    if a == "y" or a == "yes":
        print("You inputted Yes!")
        break
    elif a == "n" or a == "no":
        print("You inputted No!")
        break
    else:
        print("Please input a valid option!")
```

So if the user inputted 'Y312eS2', then it would accept that as a 'yes' answer. I want to know how it works though, because I have to explain it and all examples of `.join()` on the internet don't use it this time.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How `join()` works? It is the same as string concatenation using `+`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c for c in a if c.isalpha()
```

iterates over all characters in `a` and yields only the ones that are alpha but not numeric (`c.isalpha() is True`)

```
''.join(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

[concatenates the list of characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) to one string without separators:

```
ABC
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood it concatenates the string but did not know that it loops over all of the characters and only returns the alpha-characters, thank you :))

Comment: Just a small note, `isalpha()` returns False for an integer string ('1', '2' and so on..), so the statement `iterates over all characters in a and yields only the ones that are alphanumeric` should be changed to `iterates over all characters in a and yields only the ones that are letters`. There is another method for alphanumeric, `.isalnum()`

Answer (score 0):

You have a [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). This method simply puts all values in the iterable argument (which must be strings) together into a new string with the string object on which you called it as the joiner:

```
>>> ' - '.join(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
'foo - bar - baz'
>>> ', '.join(['spam', 'eggs', 'ham'])
'spam - eggs - ham'
```

In your example, the *empty* string `''` is used, so there is nothing separating the strings being joined:

```
>>> ''.join(['Py', 'thon'])
'Python'
```

The input to the method is a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
(c for c in a if c.isalpha())
```

This simply passes on all characters from `a` to the `str.join()` method if they are *letters*; [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) only returns true then, and not for numbers or whitespace or any other type of character:

```
>>> '1'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'c'.isalpha()
True
```

So `''.join(c for c in a if c.isalpha())` joins all characters from `c` that are letters into a new string, effectively filtering out *anything else*.

Answer (score 0):

`.join()` it self has nothing do to with removing certain characters from a string, or validating anything.

`.join()` simply takes the string that it was called upon (`'x'` in case of `'x'.join()`), concats it to every string in the iterable it got as a parameter and returns the whole thing as a single string.

For example:

```
'*'.join(['1', '2'])
>>  '1*2'
```

In the example in your code, a conditional statement was added to the iterable that was passed to `.join()`, so it would take only the strings that are letters.

Answer (score 0):

the .join() method is usually used to convert a list to a string.

you have a list comprehension plugged in to the method.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

The list is built, and the .join() method concatenates each character in the list you've built with a separation character (in your case, none '').

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join